how to use the choosing and chosen lenses?
Consider these datatypes:
data SomeNestedData = SomeNestedData { sndValue :: Int }
data OtherNestedData = OtherNestedData { ondValue :: Int }
data Foo = Bar SomeNestedData | Baz OtherNestedData

How about constructing a lens Lens' Foo Int that would get and set a value of type Int regardless of the value of some foo :: Foo?
There is choosing and assuming canonical lenses (and prisms) for the above datatypes we can do:
lensFooInt :: Lens' (Either Foo Foo) Int
lensFooInt = (_Bar . _sndValue ) `choosing` (_Baz . ondValue)

But look at the type of lensFooInt. That's not what I expected.
Leading to two questions:

How to use lensFooInt in a meaningful way? The Either kind of rules out that it works like I thought.
Is there a way to achieve some lensFooInt' :: Lens' Foo Int?

Edit: I can actually do this:
lensFooInt' = re _Right . ((_Bar . _sndValue ) `choosing` (_Baz . ondValue))


It doesn't look to me at first glance that choosing is helpful for this. It essentially says "given lenses looking into two (potentially) different structures at the same inner type, you can make a lens that looks into an Either of the two structures". You seem to want something that says "given two prisms looking into the same structure at the same inner  type (that constitute a complete match), make a lens looking into that structure".

Your lensFooInt' fails if you give it a Bar though, right? I don't think there's an easy way to do this without implementing it yourself (look at the implementation of chosen for inspiration). As @Ben says, there would be an implicit assumption that the two prisms constitute a complete match, which cannot be checked in types. lens doesn't like implicit assumptions, so that would at least reside in Control.Lens.Unsound, but it doesn't look like anything in there helps.

Related: How can I write a lens for a sum type

If you really must use choosing, write an Iso' Foo (Either SomeNestedData OtherNestedData) to get your data into the shape it expects.

As far as I can see, lensFooInt and lensFooInt' won't type check as lenses (even after correcting the ondValue typo).  Both _Bar . _sndValue and _Baz . _ondValue are prisms, not lenses, so you can't pass them to choosing and expect to get a lens.  At best, you'll get a traversal for lensFooInt. I don't think anything works for lensFooInt'.  If I focus on the problem, rather than the proposed choosing solution, I think this is a pretty exact duplicate of @duplode's link, so I'm going to vote to close.
