lens to access fields in sum type
For example, here is the sum type
 data Fruit = Apple Int Color Date
            | Banana Color Date

The Date is purchase date but it sits in different location for Apple and Banana. I'm able to make Prism via makePrisms ''Fruit
Is it possible to create a Lens like:
purchaseDate :: Lens Fruit Date

Then I can easily get/set/modify on purchase date for all fruits ( both Apple and Banana)?
I think it is different with How can I write a lens for a sum type as the field location is different ¨Date" is in different locations of value constructors

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79187140/how-to-use-the-choosing-and-chosen-lenses and others.

This question is similar to: How can I write a lens for a sum type. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This isn't a duplicate of either of those.  This is asking about a sum type with constructors sharing a common field, not a sum type of types each of which has a field with a common type.

That's a good point!

I'd still call this a duplicate.  The linked duplicate seems to be a strictly harder problem.  I'd claim, for example, that Daniel Wagner's answer to the linked duplicate should be enough information to infer the answer Daniel Wagner has given to this question.

If you give the fields common names, then makeLenses will generate appropriate lenses.  That is, after:
data Color = Red | Yellow deriving (Show)
newtype Date = Date Int deriving (Show)

data Fruit = Apple { _tree :: Int
                   , _color :: Color
                   , _date :: Date }
           | Banana { _color :: Color
                    , _date :: Date }
           deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Fruit

there will be color and date lenses:
λ> :t date
date :: Lens' Fruit Date
λ> Apple 1 Red (Date 20241217) ^. date
Date 20241217
λ> Banana Yellow (Date 20250101) ^. date
Date 20250101

For fields that aren't in common, like tree, they'll be made traversals instead:
λ> :t tree
tree :: Traversal' Fruit Int


thanks, what if itś not a record type but a ADT type (like the one in question )? The field Date can´t be access via a field name "date", and the location is different from banana and apple

@ShawnZhang You can just write the same code that makeLenses would write, but with case instead of field accesses.

@ShawnZhang I think it's also possible that you missed that the type shown here is like the one in your question. It has two different constructors, Apple and Banana, just like yours, and the date field does in fact appear in different locations for the two.

It's pretty mechanical to write lenses; that's why makeLenses exists. But if makeLenses doesn't quite do the thing you want, then of course you're free to write your favorite variation by hand!
purchaseDate :: Lens' Fruit Date
purchaseDate f = \case
    Apple i c d -> Apple i c <$> f d
    Banana c d -> Banana c <$> f d

The lens for extracting the color is extremely similar, though slightly syntactically noisier for fairly uninteresting reasons.
fruitColor :: Lens' Fruit Color
fruitColor f = \case
    Apple i c d -> f c <&> \c' -> Apple i c' d
    Banana c d -> f c <&> \c' -> Banana c' d

